# Video autoplay in HTML, JS, video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I have a problem with video autoplay with sound in HTML. I am using video.js also.
The problem is that I can't make the video to autoplay while sound is not muted on the video.
But I have the example, which I will link at the end, where video autoplay works with sound.

So I have this code in html:

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" playsinline controls>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and this code in JS:

```
var videoPlayer = videojs('video');
videoPlayer.ready(function() {
    var promise = videoPlayer.play();
});
```

And this code wont make the video to play automatically.

Here is an [example](https://video.corriere.it/cronaca/tensione-mondragone-italiani-comunita-bulgara-sedie-balconi-auto-distrutte/0e1955f6-b716-11ea-877f-fd70c3a48db9) where autoplay with sound is working. I need something like this, but cant figure out how they implemented it.

Would appreciate any advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can autoplay a video only if it is muted.You are trying to achieve something which is not possible as per chrome autoplay policy.

Read the [autoplay policy changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Comment: Thank you, but still it works on the example I provided. How can that be possible?
Also might you tell me what other interactions with domain might help me to achive play with sound?
It says "User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.)" in google policy article. What stands for "etc."?

Comment: Video may be autoplayed in firefox and safari but you cannot explicitly do this for chrome.There may be sites playing videos unmuted but they might have been created before the change in the policy came.See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay).It works here but you copy the same code and it won't work.So, accept the fact that you can't.

Comment: well, its wierd that on the old sites it is still working, how would google track that? And I am trying all I can to make it work... Its important to me... Can't just give up like that.
Also on the site I linked as an example it says that its news from 20 June 2020. Also it does not work ideally there and sometimes on some browsers it wont autoplay with sound. But on the Chrome it does autoplay. So I would asssume they used some kind of magic :)

Comment: Requires a little research about how some sites are able to.As per chrome autoplay policies, you cannot do it.So it's better to accept this because I have seen people wasting a lot of energy and time over this.

Comment: I have made research and was not able to find any info how they did that. So this was my initial question, how they managed to do autoplay with sound. Maybe someone knows a secret or someone can take a look on that site and figure out how they solved this problem.
Yeah, its true, thanks, but you have to waste energy and time if you have to get it done.

Comment: You can't get things done forcefully (like when you are not allowed to do).Spending time and energy on good problem statements is exciting, but when the policies say you can't and then if you try doing it explicitly, then it may be wastage of time and energy.Good luck.

Comment: Count me as one more voice advocating not wasting your time on this inconsistency.  (Here's my latest example of my beating my head against the wall, once an issue is one that nobody is willing to fix.): https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/58554743   Cheers...

Comment: @Dave I dont see any relation of the issue you linked to my problem.